# How to process files only for a day before using Talend?

Tags: java, talend

I have used tFileList in Talend to get files from a VM remote, which will be generated each day. I want to pick files only for the past hour and do the required processing.
I have referred to this question in StackOverflow like below :
[How to process files only for the past hour using Talend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550213/how-to-process-files-only-for-the-past-hour-using-talend)
I am stuck at step of writing code in tJavaRow. The error is :
**# "output_row cannot be resolved to a variable"**
Here is my job : .

[image]

Here is my code in tJavaRow_1 :

```
((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_5_CURRENT_FILEPATH")) = input_row

Date lastModifiedDate = TalendDate.parseDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", input_row.mtime_string);

Date current_date = TalendDate.getCurrentDate();


if(TalendDate.diffDate(current_date, lastModifiedDate,"dd") <= 1) {

output_row.abs_path = input_row.abs_path;
}
```

Could you help me to resolve this error?

I have tried some solutions but it didn't work. Like changing output_row to tJavaRow_1 or Output because I see this schema of tJavaRow_1 .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first there is an issue with the tJavaRow output, you linked the tFileInputDelimited and the tJavaRow with an if link it wont work

[image]

So to do what I think you want to do is change the if to a main output to a tFlowToIterate component (https://help.talend.com/r/fr-FR/7.3/orchestration/tflowtoiterate) and then link the tFileInputDelimited with a iterate flow like this :

[image]

you store in the tFlowToIterate the path and name of the file you want to read

[image]

And then use this var in the tFileInput like this  :

[image]